# How to check if a particular cell in JTable is being edited?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I should be able to check if a cell is being edited during mouse hover by passing the column and row:

```
TableCellEditor cellEditor = table.getCellEditor(rowPoint, colPoint);
```

In the above example `cellEditor` doesn't provide a way to check whether is in edit mode.

On the other hand, by checking `table.isEditing()` is not enough because it returns `true` if any one of the cells is being edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cell that is currently being edited:

```
JTable.getEditingRow();
JTable.getEditingColumn();
```

These 2 methods return the index of the row and column that contains the cell currently being edited. If nothing is being edited, they return `-1`.